# Use a value from reflection in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to access the value of a Contact in a LINQ Query through reflection. I am using .NET C#.

So I have a data class where I use reflection too get a value from a property that has a specific attribute (`[ConexioSearchField]`).

Example:

```
[ConexioSearchField]
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

This is the code where I do it right now:

```
//Starting the Linq Query
var unitOfWork = new SynchronizationUnitOfWork(_context);
var repository = unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<TC>();
var entities = repository.Queryable();

var firstOrDefault = EntityTypeDescriptorStore.GetEntityTypeDescriptor<TC>().Properties.FirstOrDefault(sf => sf.IsSearchField);
if (firstOrDefault == null) return entities;

var propertyInfo = firstOrDefault.PropertyInfo;

entities = type == HandledType.Doubtful
                ? entities.Where(entity1 => entity1.IsDoubtful && propertyInfo.GetValue(entity1).ToString().Contains(nameFilter))
                : entities.Where(entity1 => propertyInfo.GetValue(entity1).ToString().Contains(nameFilter));
```

But this is the error that I have:

```
Test method Conexio.Core.Orchestration.Test.Doubtfuls.SearchContactsTest.TestSearch3 threw 

exception: 
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.StringTranslatorUtil.ConvertToString(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linqExpression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ToStringTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateFunctionIntoLike(MethodCallExpression call, Boolean insertPercentAtStart, Boolean insertPercentAtEnd, Func`5 defaultTranslator)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.StringContainsTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, ref DbExpressionBinding binding)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, ref DbExpression source, ref DbExpressionBinding sourceBinding, ref DbExpression lambda)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, ref DbExpression source, ref DbExpressionBinding sourceBinding, ref DbExpression lambda)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetResultsAsync>b__a()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<ForEachAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Conexio.Core.Orchestration.Contacts.Doubtfuls.SearchDoubtfuls`3.<SearchAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in SearchDoubtfuls.cs: line 59
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Conexio.Core.Orchestration.Contacts.ConexioEntityBL`3.<SearchDoubtfulsAsync>d__28.MoveNext() in ConexioEntityBL.cs: line 323
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Conexio.Core.Orchestration.Test.Doubtfuls.SearchContactsTest.TestSearch3() in SearchContactsTest.cs: line 77
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding D Stanley answer on building expression, here is the expression.

```
var entity1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity));
var nameFilterExp = Expression.Call(
    Expression.Property(entity1, firstOrDefault.PropertyInfo.Name),
    typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }),
    Expression.Constant(nameFilter)
);
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, bool>>(
    type == HandledType.Doubtful
        ? (Expression)Expression.AndAlso(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(entity1, "IsDoubtful"), Expression.Constant(true)), nameFilterExp)
        : (Expression)nameFilterExp,
    entity1);
entities = entities.Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that EF is trying to turn your `Where` conditions into SQL `WHERE` clauses, and doesn't know what to do with the reflection calls.

A few options:

1. Use the `propertyInfo` to generate an `Expression` that EF *can* translate to SQL
2. Use [Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Can you maybe help me how I can make my properyInfo in the Expression?

Comment: @Ghost You can search SO to find several questions related to that.

Comment: @D Stanley I am trying to find somebody who has the same problem but cannot find it :)